# Android Test Case - how to view output?

Tags: android, unit-testing

I'm using `AndroidTestCase` for unit testing. I have a unit test which is failing, but I haven't figured out how to display output from it. For example, I don't see the values I print using `Log.d` or `System.out.println` in the console nor the logcat output.

How do I view the unit test console?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You shoud see the `Log.d()` messages in `logcat` unless your test is crashing much before (i.e in the constructor).

Answer (score 53):

With **Android Studio 2.3.1**, works using the old fashioned *Java styled*

```
System.out.println("Start Test");
```

Here you can see the output:

[image]

Answer (score 7):

In my case ,

`System.out.println("Test")` is working **for JUnits tests**,

`Log.d("tag" , "Test")` is working for **AndroidJUnit tests(Instrumented)**

Answer (score 6):

Go to Debug --> Logcat.  Make sure the LogLevel and Filter are correct as well.

See the screenshot from Android Studio 1.1.0

[image: From Android Studio 1.1.0]

Answer (score 2):

Just to be clear, if you're running an emulator you have to use `adb logcat`.

Also, make sure you're using the standard `android.util.Log.d()` to send your output.

Comment: Android Studio running Unit tests doesn't always connect to a device. In my case, there is no emulator or phone, robolectric tests are run entirely in the jre.

Answer (score 0):

You probably disconnected the device/emulator and reconnected. You have to click on the device name again in the list in the Dalvik Debug Monitor for it to reload the logs and keep updating the output.