# System.out.println in android test

Tags: java, android

I have created simple test in Android Studio. It just prints `hello from test` and compares `1` with `5`

```
package com.example.maks.firstapp.test;

import android.test.InstrumentationTestCase;

public class ExampleTest extends InstrumentationTestCase {
    public void test() throws Exception {
        System.out.println("hello from test");

        final int expected = 1;
        final int reality = 5;
        assertEquals(expected, reality);
    }
}
```

I run it but don't see `hello from test` anywhere.

The output:

```
Running tests
Test running started
junit.framework.AssertionFailedError: expected:<1> but was:<5>
at com.example.maks.firstapp.test.ExampleTest.test(ExampleTest.java:15)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at android.test.InstrumentationTestCase.runMethod(InstrumentationTestCase.java:214)
at android.test.InstrumentationTestCase.runTest(InstrumentationTestCase.java:199)
at android.test.AndroidTestRunner.runTest(AndroidTestRunner.java:190)
at android.test.AndroidTestRunner.runTest(AndroidTestRunner.java:175)
at android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner.onStart(InstrumentationTestRunner.java:555)
at android.app.Instrumentation$InstrumentationThread.run(Instrumentation.java:1661)

Finish
```

Where to `System.out.println` does actually print

## Update

I tried to use `Log.d("MyApp", "hello from test");` but result is the same.

I tried to search in different sub-windows by `hello from test` but nothing was found.

## Update 2

I changed code to use `e.Log`:

```
package com.example.maks.firstapp.test;

import android.test.InstrumentationTestCase;
import android.util.Log;

public class ExampleTest extends InstrumentationTestCase {
    public void test() throws Exception {
        Log.e("MyApp", "I am here");

        final int expected = 1;
        final int reality = 5;
        assertEquals(expected, reality);
    }
}
```

Screenshots:

**Test is done.**
[image: Running test]

**But `logcat` is empty.**
[image: empty logcat]

Comment: I haven't done unit testing on Android before (hey, good on you!) but in Android Studio, there's a tab called Logs or something, and you can use the search box to filter logs.

Comment: @gengkev I checked out duplicate and tried `Log.d` and tried to search by `hello from test` but it did not help.

Comment: According to http://stackoverflow.com/q/5451614/ `Log.d` should work...

Comment: Try http://developer.android.com/tools/help/logcat.html

Comment: search by "MyApp" (the first argument)

Comment: @svarog  where should I search? `logcat` is totally empty (please see screenshot above)

Comment: have you tried adb logcat ?

Comment: @svarog oh, thank you, `E/MyApp   (15737): I am here` was found using `adb logcat` in terminal

Comment: Then I guess you either didn't search with the right log tag name or your Android Studio logcat isn't configured properly

Answer (score 6):

Use `Log` to print out strings and check them in your `logcat`.

There are different variants you can base on your need like `Log.d`, `Log.i`, `Log.e`, etc which are for different purposes like debug, info, error, etc.

And make sure the proper 'Log level' for your `logcat` is selected. If it's on `Error` you won't see the output for `Log.d`.

[Further read](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Log.html)

[image]
[image]

Comment: I tried `Log.e` so with any `Log level` I must see my message, but I do not see it.

Comment: If that's the issue then I can only imagine that the part of code has somehow never reached (or the build fails or something). If the app runs then just try `Log.e` on your first activity right after `setContentView` just for test.

Comment: If Android Studio throws "cannot find symbol variable log" do not forget to add at the top of your class the  import android.util.Log;

Answer (score 0):

This problem happens when the class is in the wrong test folder!, Change to the folder you have (test).
Your class is possibly in the folder (AndroidTest)

Comment: Since it is an instrumentation test case, it should be in androidTest folder only.